# SQL 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-data-factory

I am creating a pipeline from the SQL database to storage in the Azure data factory.

I am struggling to identify how to search data between the two dates with this format: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`

I created a variable for the date called: date

[image]

Now upon searching query with below codes:

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM dbo.Task_History 
WHERE history_timestamp BETWEEN ''2015-01-01T01:00:00Z'' AND CONVERT(datetime2, ''' , variables('date') , ''', 127)')
```

It gives an error stating:

> *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

[image]

Below is the target column where to search the target data

[image]

Comment: What is `variables('date')` here?

Comment: When you're constructing a query via string concatenation (but please lean towards using parameters instead to keep data and code separate and avoid SQL injection) and the query isn't working, please print out the *entire final query*. You'll either spot the issue yourself or should include it in your question.

Comment: 1 moment im looking how to edit. Thanks!

Comment: This is really a complex and multiple ingestion of data, I just created a simplified query to make it easier to understand, I apologize for the query inside concatination.

Comment: The [Parameterize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services) chapter in the ADF docs shows how to define strongly typed parameters and variables and use them in expressions. You can define strongly-typed variables and parameters and use them with string interpolation, eg `WHERE dateOnPrem BETWEEN @{pipeline().parameters.start_date} AND @{pipeline().parameters.end_date}`

Comment: In any case dates in a SQL database have no format. They're binary values, just like int, bigint, bit, decimal etc. Client tools like SSMS display them using the ISO861 format because it's the only unambiguous format, not because the dates themselves have any format

Comment: *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.* - this is one of the reasons to use parameters instead of concatenation as they are typed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos seems like yes, because the query is working to other tables, but this table doesn't.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I already updated my post, the variable date captures the current timestamp.

Comment: @JuanEnriqueBanal it's not the table. It's the expression. You're wide open to SQL injection and conversion problems. Don't use concat. Use what the documentation shows - string interpolation with strongly typed parameters

Comment: @JuanEnriqueBanal unless `history_timestamp` is a string instead of a proper `datetime2`? This is the same bug, on the table's side this time - using localized strings instead of the proper date type, eg `date`, `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset`. The solution again is to use the correct type. Either change the field type to a date, or handle everything as a text - use the variables as strings instead of trying to convert them to dates.

Comment: Don't use `concat` just use a parameterized query `WHERE history_timestamp BETWEEN '2015-01-01T01:00:00Z' AND @date`

Answer (score 0):

​You can use convertFromUtc() function to get current date time in Singapore Standard time zone. And then you can use string interpolation syntax for dynamically building your SQL query.

In below example, I am trying to build a SQL query which will query data from "dbo.Task_History" table between dates "2015-01-01T01:00:00Z" & current date time Singapore Standard time zone.

**Set variable activity to set current date time value in Singapore Standard time zone.**

Expression used: @convertFromUtc(utcnow(),'Singapore Standard Time')
[image]
**Generating SQL query using String Interpolation format:**

SELECT * FROM dbo.Task_History
WHERE history_timestamp BETWEEN '2015-01-01T01:00:00Z' AND '@{variables('singaPoreDateTime')}'

Between, could you pls help me understand why you are trying to convert again in SQL to some timezone ?